# Having extra parameters in piping or redirection

Tags: pipe, io-redirection

I have two programs and I want to pipe them into each other but they take extra parameters:

```
prog1 <inputfile> <outputfile> min max
prog2 <inputfile> <outputfile> min max
```

What would be the syntax be like to pipe them together? Would the parameters affect it?

Also would piping automatically sort the prog1's output?

Comment: Do you mean you want the output of `prog1` to be the inputfile of `prog2`?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 2):

If `prog2` follows a common convention you could use `-` as the "file" to tell it to read from stdin and then the pipeline would be

```
prog1 <inputfile> - min max | prog2 - <outputfile> min max
```

which would tell prog1 to write to `stdout` as its output file, and `prog2` would use `stdin` as its input file with the pipe connecting those two.

This would not automatically sort them, but you could add that to the pipeline:

```
prog1 <inputfile> - min max | sort | prog2 - <outputfile> min max
```

And parameters don't affect the pipeline.  You just need to make sure that the programs in the pipeline know how to read from stdin (if they're on the right side of a pipe) and write to stdout (if they're on the left side of a pipe).

Comment: I'll try that and I'll let you know the result, thanks.